# MVC Single String JSON post always coming Null in Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am facing a strange problem in my MVC 5 application where I want to pass a Drop Down Selected value to controller using a Ajax post.

the Post code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    //Change the Value stream list each time the BU is selected
    $('#Lob').change(function () {   

        alert(JSON.stringify($('#Lob option:selected').text()));

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/GetValueStreams/")',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify($('#Lob option:selected').text()),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (VSList) {
                // do stuff
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The ALERT works fine and displays the selected value correctly. However in the controller, the string appears as null.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetValueStreams(string BUName)
    {   
       // Here the BUName parameter is coming as null.
    }
```

I have tried changing my JSON POST data to the following:

```
data: {"BUName": JSON.stringify($('#Lob option:selected').text())},
```

This also does not work. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without quotes on BUName should work

Comment: No need for to stringify a string: `data: {"BUName": $('#Lob option:selected').text()},` - but you should be getting something in BUName, so there's a problem *elsewhere*.

Comment: Why JSON type? You’re passing a string

Comment: I think “contentType: JSON” is also out of place

Comment: Not the problem, but worth mentioning:  Use `url: '@Url.Action("GetValueStreams", "Dashboard")',`

Comment: @DavideVitali you're correct - `dataType` is the response, so not relevant to the question while `contentType` is what's being sent and should work with the default for MVC (ie not specified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data to `data: JSON.stringify({BUName : $('#Lob option:selected').text()})`.

I tested and it worked.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/GetValueStreams/")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({BUName : $('#Lob option:selected').text()}),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (VSList) {
            // do stuff
        }
        });
```